# Restore HDD state after making it all one partition

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

While I was trying to copy windows installation from ISO file to a USB Disk using "WinToFlash" software, I accidentally choose one of my partitions "I had three Partition, I choose the third (E:/)", I clicked started and suddenly the blue screen appeared. When I restarted my Device, only the word "j" was in the Dos screen, and windows didn't boot. 
Now I plugged it in my other Computer as an external HDD, it shows up as a single unformatted partition, it says it's all free, and the File System is Raw, and the state is "Healthy (Active, Primary Partition).

So I understand that it wasn't formatted, which means the files are still in there. I don't care about the Operating System, I only need my files. How can I access to them ?

Comment: If you don't have a record of the partition layout, then google for a partition recovery tool.  Your files should be safe, but don't do anything else with this disk until you have run the recovery.  And keep backups!

Comment: If you chose the third partition, then you blew away the data on that partition.  The other partitions should have been unaffected.

Comment: Check out testdisk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recuva works great in the past. You've good opportunity to recover all your files using this tool if that's not been overwritten(hoping for this will be true). You can also use advanced partition recovery tool if recuva fails to do the needed job. Use TestDisk, Active@Partition Recovery or Stellar Phoenix instead.